Matplotlib axes caption with automatic wrapping
In Matplotlib, I have two plots next to each other and I'd like to add a caption to each to them. I'd like the caption auto-wrapped to fit under the respective axes pair.
I've tried
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)

axs[0].plot([1.0, 1.2, 0.9])
axs[0].text(
    0,
    -0.1,
    """
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
    veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
    velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
    est laborum.
    """,
    transform=axs[0].transAxes,
    wrap=True,
)
plt.show()

but got

The wrap setting doesn't seem to do the trick.
What does?

This might be a good use case for subfigures, though I'm getting mixed results.

@BigBen what Matplotlib version do you have?  There was this fix in v3.9.1: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/28401

Subfigures do the trick!
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
subfigs = fig.subfigures(1, 2)

ax = subfigs[0].add_subplot()
ax.plot([1.0, 1.2, 0.9])
ax.text(
    0,
    -0.1,
    """
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
    veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
    velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
    est laborum.
    """,
    wrap=True,
    ha="left",
    fontsize=12,
    transform=ax.transAxes,
)

ax = subfigs[1].add_subplot()
ax.plot([1.0, 1.2, 0.9])
ax.text(
    0,
    -0.1,
    """
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium
    doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore
    veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim
    ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia
    consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque
    porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur,
    adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore
    et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis
    nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid
    ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea
    voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui
    dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    """,
    wrap=True,
    ha="left",
    fontsize=12,
    transform=ax.transAxes,
)

plt.show()


